# how to change root node wcf request\response

Tags: wcf, root-node

I am calling a Java webservice which I am trying to call from WPF client using Gateway and message inspector. The problem I am facing is -- Java webservice requires the root node of request xml as  element, however my WCF request (When i am inspecting it in MessageInspector-beforeSendRequest) contains the Operation contract name as root node.

Is there any way that I can remove start and end Operation name nodes from the request and send a request with start with  node directly.

Same issue is there when I get the response from Service

I just joined this community. And I did try search it. But somehow there are no pointers for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The soap standard allows different styles of soap envelope XML structure. Microsoft by default uses a style known document/literal/wrapped instead of document/literal. They had their reasons but it can make integration with certain types of java services difficult.

To get java & WCF to play nice, you may need to manually configure your WCF client classes to conform to the soap style of document/literal. A good description of the problem is [in this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-whichwsdl/), [also in this article](http://pzf.fremantle.org/2007/05/handlign.html) and [here too.](http://www.designpatternsfor.net/default.aspx?pid=115) How much you'll need to change the structure of the WCF client classes generated by SvcUtil to emit the correctly formatted soap will depend on the java service requirements but this should get you started.